# attributes.class.value on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, function, class, internet-explorer-8, attributes

I am trying to find the sum of input tags that have classes named `numberinput`
How the highligthed (with stars) line is supported by IE 8?
Because on Chrome or Firefox it works perfectly.

```
function sum() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof elem[i].attributes.class !== "undefined") {
            **if(elem[i].attributes.class.value === "numberinput")**{
                names.push(elem[i].value);
            }
        }
     }
    var inputValues = names;
    var counter=0;
    for (var i=0; i<inputValues.length; i++){
        counter=inputValues[i]*1+counter;
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = counter;
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the w3schools the line should work normally since IE 2.0

```
elem[i].attributes.class.value === "numberinput"
```

You can use it with no worries!

Comment: so might there is anything else in this script that could not work in IE8??
Since this code doesnt work out there. No idea why.